# Code analysis violations not being reported

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

We have several codeanalysis violations in our solutions that are not firing. Here's an example:

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private readonly int _factor = 1;

        protected int Test1(object val)
        {
            if (val == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(val));
            }
            return Blop(val.GetHashCode());
        }

        protected int Test2(object val)
        {
            return Blop(val.GetHashCode());
        }

        protected int Test3(object val)
        {
            if (val == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(val));
            }
            return Blop(val.GetHashCode());
        }

        private int Blop(int value)
        {
            return value * _factor;
        }
    }
}
```

If running code analysis, this will report:

```
Class1.cs(20): error CA1062: Microsoft.Design : In externally visible method 'Class1.Test2(object)', validate parameter 'val' before using it.
```

What is absolutely correct. **But if you remove either one or both of the two if/throw blocks code analysis is not reporting any of the now two/three violations.** Which does not make sense IMHO.

We have similar behaviours with CA1031 (Do not catch general exception types), CA1822 (Mark members as static) and others.

Are these bugs in the rules (can it be that there are so many of them)? Or do they only appear on large solutions (we have ~60 projects)? Could it be a problem with a mix of Roslyn and Non-Roslyn rules/checks? Or is the StyleCop.Analyzers NuGet package that we use interfering somehow?

Any ideas how to solve this or at least where/whom to address this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I try this, I end up with three warnings as expected. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3, and "Microsoft All Rules" ruleset. So it appears to work correctly for a small example - does it work for you?

Comment: As stated above I do not get the errors any more when removing one or both of the if/throw blocks. Not in the big solution, not in a small sample. I'm also using VS2015 U3.

Comment: This may be a long shot, but could this have anything to do with the "Enable full solution analysis" option being turned off?